# Require a parameter type for input tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a custom focus method for my page, which is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
    }
</script>
```

The reason why I'm using this and not just `autofocus` is that I'm moving from one page to another. Therefore I need to click on a button on one html page and then have focus on the input tag for another page. My function is working correctly as I have been able to test it using this:

```
 <input type="text" onmousemove=myFunction() id="focus">
```

However I don't want to use onmousemove, I want it to be automatic. So when the page is loaded it will then focus immediately. Is there are tag for this? If there is a possibility of using the button from HTML page 1 and get it to focus on the input box on HTML page 2, that would be good but I'm unsure how/if that is possible. Thanks.

Comment: There is `autofocus` HTML tag. And to set is, you can use PHP POST or GET methods on button and check it on 2nd page. Or use JS with cookie or local storage  like answer below suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this:

1: You pass query parameters in the URL of the second page using a ?:

```
document.getElementById("linkId").setAttribute("href","https://example.com?something");
```

And have javascript on the second page to check for it.

2: A better way of doing it would be to use `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.setItem("focus","true");
```

Code on second page:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("focus")==="true"){
  element.focus();
}
```